# Trying to build PWA with nativescripts

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a new nativescript app that I want to run on web (besides mobile), but when I run `ng serve` I get

```
ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: No projects support the serve target.
See /private/var/folders/wz/v4mcrr4n35v9q72wbvlzwqnh0000gn/T/ng-UsAqii/angular-errors.log for further details.
```

And in that log file:

```
[error] Error: No projects support the 'serve' target.
    at ServeCommand.initialize (/.../node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:53:19)
    at async ServeCommand.validateAndRun (/.../node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command.js:124:9)
    at async Object.runCommand (/.../node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:186:24)
    at async default_1 (/.../node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js:54:31)
```

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "frame-ui": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.2.0",
    "nativescript-image-filters": "^2.2.2",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~7.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^0.7.2",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~8.2.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^8.3.14",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
```

Comment: you can't have 100 % same code for nativesript android/ios app and web app. At least you have to rewrite HTML templates and change package.json for web with angular web dependencies: you can't use nativescript-angular packages for web.

Comment: If you are creating a new project, try adding {N} schematics to existing web project generated by Angular CLI. That should help you run both easily.

Comment: @Manoj do you mean, first create an angular project and then make it a nativescript one? I alreadu have @nativescript/schematics in my nativescript app.

Comment: Yes, that will be easier to setup since you are creating new project. Otherwise you will have to configure `angular.json` yourself manually.